# Footer is not at the bottom of the homepage

Tags: html, css

[heres the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI4Q0.png)  I tried several methods on how to align the footer at the bottom but I haven't found any solution what method should I use to solve the problem?

```
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="footer-nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="footer-nav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="social-link">
                <img src="/img/iconmonstr-facebook-2.svg" alt="" />
                Facebook
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="social-link">
                <img src="/img/iconmonstr-instagram-11.svg" />
                Instagram
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows how your footer isn't at the bottom of the page. Nothing in your HTML indicates that it _should_ be at the bottom. Stack Overflow isn't for guesses. (And even if it was, then we would still point you to the same solutions that you already tried and didn't work for you.)

Comment: Try setting a minimum height of `100vh` for your body, or setting your `footer` to have `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Add style to the footer element:

```
style="position:absolute; bottom:0px"
```

Comment: I try this  method sir but it wont stay in the bottom

Comment: @LanzeIvan this is because you have bootstrap container inside the footer? try remove it or set the position on the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` as recommended by avi,
But I generally recommend against absolute where possible.

This can be also solved using flexbox.
set the flex-direction to column,
and set `flex: 1` on the main part which you want to take all space (generally you don't want the header and footer to expand)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header<</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

> NOTE: you must set the body and html height to 100% in order for that to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/jszht5xp/19/